# Nuclear resonance spectroscopy: why not use Co-57 radioactive source instead of synchrotron?

Tags: nuclear-physics, spectroscopy

In [nuclear resonant spectroscopy experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_resonance_vibrational_spectroscopy), typically a sample containing Fe-57 nuclei is used. These nuclei are then excited via a synchrotron-based X-ray source.

Why is it not common to simply use a Co-57 source as a means to excite sample nuclei (instead of the synchrotron)? The Co-57 nuclei also emit 14.4 keV X-rays/gammas from the decay of excited Fe-57 nuclei they turn into.

Comment: The synchrotron makes a nice high brightness beam that you can turn on and off.

Comment: Yes, but technically you could achieve high brightness with a strong source (which would still be more convenient to handle than requiring an entire synchrotron) and you could also turn it on and off from the perspective of the sample by blocking it with a large lead brick. I wonder whether a major reason is the energy loss of photons emitted from Fe-57 due to recoil, which should be about 20 meV if I'm not mistaken. That difference could possibly be enough to miss the narrow 14 412.5 eV line to excite other Fe-57 nuclei.

Comment: Well, you have a synchrotron for many reasons. And high intensity Co sources have lots of regulations…

Comment: Sure, thanks, but I'm hoping for a more precise answer based on the physics involved.